# Open source Java Thread server

Tags: java, multithreading, backend, server

I am looking for some opensource in Java thats able to do following things

1.Run some number of threads
2.Have a control on each one of those threads ( like if I want to shutdown some of them - I can do it)

anyone knows something like that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are looking implementation of thread pool. Fortunately JDK has one built-in. Take a look on Exectutors framework.